# Google Maps And Eclipse Not Dancing (the import com.google cannot be resolved)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm attempting to add google maps to Eclipse but getting the message ( **the import com.google cannot be resolved**)
[image]

It seem to have tried everything including windows->Sdk manager
[image]

Found these but unsure if it has downloaded correctly 
[image]

Cant click apply here
[image]

Comment: It'd be easier to resolve this problem if you used Gradle (or Android Studio)

Comment: Why would you use Eclipse? Please switch to Android studio!

Comment: Prefer Eclipse to be honest.

Comment: That's fine, but official support for Eclipse for Android development ended months ago. Beyond that, none of your screenshots show whether you have added the libraries to your Eclipse project (see Project > Properties > Android).

Comment: Bottom image is the one I think your talking about.

Comment: No, I don't think so. Project > Properties > Android should have a checklist of installed SDK versions, plus an area at the bottom for adding/removing libraries (or declaring that this project itself is a library). BTW, on Stack Overflow, use @ notation (akin to Twitter), to reply to commenters.